# Why do we add 4 to the desitnation when calculating the distance between two address?

Tags: assembly

I am self-studying assembly and I've seen this in the coursehero when I was doing question.
when we are trying to calculate how far is address 2(Destination) from address 1(Starting point)

Lets say address 2 is 0x1FFFFFFF and address 1 is 0x1000FFFF.

the answer showed that we should do such : Ox1FFFFFFF + 4 - 0x1000FFFF.

Where does the 4 come from ? when do we need to add that when calculating the distance?

Comment: In general, no, you don't need to add 4 to get the distance between two addresses.

Comment: There's no reason to do this in general. There's some context we're missing here.

Comment: @interjay the original questions i that given a starting address A, can we use branch or jump instruction to reach address 2. So to do that, we need to calculate the distance between two address and see if they fit into their instruction's size limit. And that's when I came across  the + 4

Comment: You also need to specify architecture. One thing that comes to mind is ARM in thumb mode.

Comment: @Jester it is mip

Comment: @Jester My guess is, the offset of jump instruction is actually 28 bits(26 shifted left by 2), so the 4 is to compensate the shifting?

Comment: No, the 4 is to compensate the automatic increment of PC. Each instruction on MIPS is 4 bytes.

Comment: so when it comes to calculating the distances between address in mips, we always +4 to compensate that?

Comment: Not always. Only in instructions that use PC relative encoding.

Comment: @Jester, thanks, that explains a lot . Last question: the instruction of Jump is 26 bits and the instruction of branch is 16 bits, then why can they actually jump as far as 2^28 and 2^18 respectively, where are the extra 2 bits come from?

Comment: The extra two come from the shift by 2. Since instructions are word aligned, the offset is stored as words, not bytes.

Comment: BTW, your example address `0x1FFFFFFF` is not word aligned (bottom two bits are not "00"), so it's not a valid instruction address, and you can't jump to such address by jump/branch instruction, a word-aligned addresses around `0x1FFFFFFF` are `0x1FFFFFFC` and `0x20000000`.